# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object

Tags: php, medoo

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in
>   **************/includes/Dbo.class.inc on line 41

Line 41:

```
public function selectCondition($database, $table, $condition, $condition_value){
  return $database->debug()->select($table, "*", array($condition => $condition_value))->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

After calling this function to get an result array it displays the error mentioned above. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `fetch` method

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://medoo.in/api/select) `select()` returns array so you can't call any other method on this result.

So your code should look like this:

```
return $database->debug()->select($table, "*", array($condition => $condition_value));
```

**edit**:
It is not working also because of debug mode. Correct code should look like this:

```
 return $database->select($table, "*", array($condition => $condition_value));
```

Comment: After removing the function fetchAll();var_dump returns a boolean(false)..

Comment: So you have db error. Try `var_dump($database->error());` to see what happened.

Comment: result from var_dump($database->error()) ´array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [2]=>
  NULL
}´

Comment: Try this  
     `$zm = $database->debug()->select($table, "*", array($condition => $condition_value));`  
      `var_dump($zm);`    

      `var_dump($database->error());`  

      `return $zm;`

Comment: result: SELECT * FROM "auftraege" WHERE "idauftrag" = '1'bool(false) array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }

Comment: Ah, I see in code, that in debug mode query is not executed at all... Just remove `->debug()`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!